# Under-determined linear problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

To compute all solution of following under-determined linear problem in matrix form
$ Ax = y $
we can use Pseudo inverse of A and the solution would be :
$ x = A^{PI}y + [I - A^{PI}A]w $
I couldn't understand why do we add $ [I - A^{PI}A]w $ to the solution.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the system $Ax=y$ is consistent ($y$ is contained in the range of $A$; otherwise, the system is not solvable), then any solution of $Ax=y$ can be written in the form of a sum of a "particular" solution and of any vector from the null-space of $A$:
$$
x=x_0+z,
$$
where $Ax_0=y$ and $Az=0$ ($Ax=A(x_0+z)=y+0=y$). With the (Moore-Penrose) pseudo-inverse of $A$ at hand, a particular solution can be obtained as
$$
x_0=A^{\mathrm{PI}}y.
$$
It can be easily seen that $Ax_0=y$. Since $y$ in the range of $A$, it can be written as $y=A\tilde{y}$ for some $\tilde{y}$. Hence $Ax_0=AA^{\mathrm{PI}}A\tilde{y}=A\tilde{y}=y$ (note that the pseudo-inverse satisfies $AA^{\mathrm{PI}}A=A$).

The orthogonal projection onto the row-space of $A$ can be written using the pseudo-inverse as $A^{\mathrm{PI}}A$ and hence $I-A^{\mathrm{PI}}A$ is the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement which is the null-space of $A$. Any vector $z$ from the null-space of $A$ can therefore be written as
$$
z=(I-A^{\mathrm{PI}}A)w
$$
for some $w$.

This gives the general form of the solution of $Ax=y$:
$$
x=A^{\mathrm{PI}}y+(I-A^{\mathrm{PI}}A)w.
$$

You can easily check that this $x$ satisfies the system (note that $y=A\tilde{y}$ since $y$ is in the range of $A$ by assumption):
$$
\begin{split}
Ax&=AA^{\mathrm{PI}}y+A(I-A^{\mathrm{PI}}A)w\\
&=AA^{\mathrm{PI}}A\tilde{y}+A(I-A^{\mathrm{PI}}A)w\\
&=\underbrace{AA^{\mathrm{PI}}A}_{=A}\;\tilde{y}+(A-\underbrace{AA^{\mathrm{PI}}A}_{=A}\;)w\\
&=A\tilde{y}+0\\&=y.
\end{split}
$$